# Getting variable from select statement after using get_object_vars ();

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got this result  `array(1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "5" }`

After a select statement request

```
$mp = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta inner join wp_posts ON post_id= %d WHERE meta_key = 'max_person'", $postid
) );
```

`var_dump(get_object_vars($mp));`

And the result should be "5"
Anybody can help me how to get "5" as integer 
5 is all what I need from the select request

Comment: It doesnt work like that... you get an array of columns and values back... just do `$value = (integer) $mp->meta_value;` or you after you use `get_object_vars` you can reference it like an array with `$varname['meta_value']`.

Comment: @prodigitalson Thank you it works.. it's much easier than I expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$value = (integer) $mp->meta_value;`